# Euchre question

Tags: euchre

Dealer turns up Ace of Spades, and he calls Spades trump and goes alone, picks up the card. First person leads an Ace of Hearts. Second person passes (hand played alone) and third person (doesn't have a heart) so throws a King of Spades. Dealer has to play a heart, instead of over trumping third player. Dealer says 3rd player is wrong to Trump first players card, because it was overtrumped their partner.

Dealer says that 3rd player should have just thrown off, something else.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thanks for your question! Are you asking whether 3rd player's play was legal? or whether it was a good idea? or something else? Please clarify. Your question might also be clearer if you remove extraneous details - e.g. if the question is about whether 3rd player's play is legal/reasonable, then it seems like Dealer's subsequent play is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I understand this question.  The question is "can you trump a partners ace?"  While it is not normal to Trump your Partner, it is allowed, and you shoud do it in Special cases, just like this. When a Player goes alone you have to know they have a good hand and are probably going to score Points. best strategy is to try to stop them from scoring 4 Points by taking all alone. IN this case I would have also trumped my Partners ace in the hope that I either take the trick or use up one of the Dealers trump Cards.